# How to solve Visio 2003's error "Invalid number" when changing font size?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-visio-2003

When editing a drawing in MS Visio 2003 I need to change the size of a text. Every time I change the number in size box the message is appearing on the screen and say "Invalid number".

I traveled the net in all directions and I didn't find a solution. I tried re-saving of the drawing, copying all contents into new file and I'm still getting this error. I think that this error is caused by shape-related damage, because it is also happening in a new file with copied text from original drawing. I'm stuck with Visio 2003, I cannot switch to later version.

Does anybody know how to solve this ? This drawing is too complex (industrial network scheme) to start it again from scratch.

Comment: Sinkien. Can you attach or send me a sample file with this problem? Send to paul at pherber dot com

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when put the number with a period, like **8.5**.

Try to put a natural number **8** or use a comma **8,5**

Comment: The decimal separator being either `,` or `.` depends on your Control panel >regional settings.

Comment: The message is shown no matter if I enter 8b, or select 8b from dropdown, or I enter 8.5 from keyboard. It just says "Invalid number"

Comment: Have you tried also 8 and 8,5?